# How to flow-type props when using react-redux connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I would like to declare that my react-redux `mapStateToProps` function is returning correctly-typed properties and not omitting any.

If I do it this way, it complains about dispatch in props. If I made it not `$Exact`, I think it wouldn't catch missing or extra props.

I was thinking that myComponent could declare a static field with type Props so I could read off the type from there, but that seems like a hack and I would need to do it for every component.

#### In `src/mycomponent/index.js`:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import type {Props} from './myComponent';
import MyComponent from './myComponent'

function mapStateToProps(state: State): $Exact<Props> {
  return {
    myKey: state.myKey,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

#### In `src/myComponent/myComponent.js`

```
type Props = {
  myKey: string,
}

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   props: Props;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use `$Exact` with props. It is not an error in React to specify extra props, and a lot of libraries depend on this behavior. If you use the `Props` type without `$Exact`, it will still catch missing props (["In JavaScript, accessing a property that doesn’t exist evaluates to undefined. This is a common source of errors in JavaScript programs, so Flow turns these into type errors."](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/)), but won't complain about extra props being passed (in fact, the behavior of object types in Flow was changed to *allow* for objects with extra fields not specified in the type)

Of course, the ideal solution here would be for Flow to allow object types to be extended, for instance:

```
type Props = { /* ... */ }
type ReduxProps = { ...Props, dispatch: /* ... */ }
```

but while this feature doesn't land, I believe it's just best to tolerate extra props to be passed. It should be reasonably safe, too, as Flow won't let you read from unknown props iirc.

Comment: You can combine proptypes with the & operator. So you could have something like `type Props = OwnProps & ReduxProps & ReduxDispatchers & etc`